# How to populate HTML fields from database data using Flask

Tags: flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to fetch data from a database using flask-alchemy, based on a string value I have passed from another screen. But here's the problem, I get a `400 error` for my password and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the function that fetches my data:

```
def userToEdit(userVar):
    with session_scope() as s:                                
        userVname = s.query(tabledef.User).filter(tabledef.User.username==userVar).first()  
        return(userVname)
```

Here is the function that process with my template:

```
# -------- Edit Users ---------------------------------------------------------- #
@app.route('/edituser/<string:userVar>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edituser(userVar):
    userV = helpers.userToEdit(userVar)
    if session.get('logged_in'):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            password = request.form['password']
            if password != "":
                password = helpers.hash_password(password)
            email = request.form['email']
            helpers.change_user(password=password, email=email)
            return json.dumps({'status': 'Saved'})
        else:
            password = helpers.fetch_usernames.password
        user = helpers.userToEdit(userVar)
        pagename = "Edit User"        
        roles = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']
        mobile_roles = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
        states = ['Active', 'Non-active']
        return render_template('edituser.html', user=user, pagename=pagename, roles=roles, states=states, mobile_roles=mobile_roles)        
    return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Here is the part of my template which should be populated:

```
<div class="field">
            <p class="control has-icons-left">
              <input id="settings-user" class="input is-success" type="text" placeholder="{{user.username}}" readonly="readonly">
              <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <p class="control has-icons-left">
              <input id="settings-mail" class="input is-success" type="text" placeholder="{{user.email}}">
              <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <p class="control has-icons-left">
              <input id="settings-pass" class="input" type="password" placeholder="&#x2022&#x2022&#x2022&#x2022&#x2022">
              <span class="icon is-small is-left">
                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
              </span>
            </p>
          </div>
```

and in case you ask the error is the following message

> werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap..newcls: 400 Bad
>   Request: KeyError: 'password'

Now that I got everything out of the way, is there a way to fix that? Because I have no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

You should add name value to your input fields like below:

```
<input id="settings-pass" class="input" type="password" name='password' 
placeholder="&#x2022&#x2022&#x2022&#x2022&#x2022">
<input id="settings-mail" class="input is-success" type="text" name='email'
placeholder="{{user.email}}">
```

Comment: That changed nothing, but thank you for your time.

Comment: you get password = request.form['password']. So if your form did not have input with name password, you will see that error.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, I get the same error